# How do I get my contact form to process additional information?

Tags: php

I have a contact form on my site using a wordpress plugin. The form is set up in a way that emails me directly the information that is filled out. I am trying to add a feature to this form that allows me to view the submitters IP address. I think I have the correct php code which is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userIP" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>">
```

The next step is to include this information in the email that is sent, on submit. Here is the code that handles post action:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
```

So all I have to do is find the process.php file, and the configuration that to include the information I want? But that's my problem: no such file exists. I cannot find it, and I've searched all over my file manager for it. Any tips / advice for this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should first learn PHP, and only after that try to do some stuff with it.

Comment: I'm learning php in the near future - but the plugin that I use already has php code. I'm just trying to work some things around, I've been successful in other areas of the site I've been tweaking.

Comment: That platform is just not for users who have not even a minimalistic understanding of PHP unfortunately. Please don't get me wrong but it would just be too hard for us to explain everything from the scratch. Altough you did not provide all the information we need.

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend adding ip address in hidden field. Append ip address in your email body contents. Have you checked process.php file in your theme directory?

Comment: Yep checked everywhere, no process.php file to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** put the ip address as a hidden field since every visitor would be able to **change** it! Search the code which is resposible for sending the e-mail. There you can add the variable to the e-mail body.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Is the correct way however.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately I cannot for the life of me find the code that is responsible for sending the e-mail. I found a form method post action code that refered to a file called process.php - would that be the file that sends the e-mail? I cannot find process.php anywhere on my server, it does not exist.

Comment: Where did you get that line of html from? Have u taken it from your live system or from some documentation?

Comment: That line of html I did not touch, it is part of the plug-in code. The only thing I'm trying to add some ip address information - to an already working contact form.

Comment: Go to your website where your form is located, then make use of something like FireBug or the Firefox/Chrome built-in element viewer (Right click on the form -> Inspect element). Check the action attribute of your form tag, is it also process.php?

Comment: Yes, it's also process.php

Comment: my site is globalleaks(dot)com